# Access/SQL: Multiple conditions on same column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

I'm stuck with the following problem:

I have a table called "Pickauf_0110" with ~80 columns and ~60000 records.

The two columns I'm interested in are: "nr_pickl" and "platz_von".

The entries in the column "nr_pickl" look like this:

```
123456
123456
123457
```

The entries in the column "platz_von" look like this:

```
03-01-00-00 
03-02-00-00
04-01-00-00
05-06-03-02
```

None of these columns are keys, so the records are not unique.

Here's what I want to find out:

How many entries in "platz_von" start with "03", how many with "04" and how many with "05" for every unique entry in "nr_pickl".

My idea was to do a triple selfjoin, with three different conditions (platz_von like '03*'...), sum these and finally group them by nr_pickl.

Here's my sql query that fails with an error:

```
    SELECT 
         p1.nr_pickl,
         sum(p1.platz_von) as Gang_03,
         sum(p2.platz_von) as Gang_04,
         sum(p3.platz_von) as Gang_05
    FROM
        ((Pickauf_0110 as p1
    INNER JOIN
        Pickauf_0110 as p2 ON p1.nr_pickl = p2.nr_pickl)
    INNER JOIN
        Pickauf_0110 as p3 ON p1.nr_pickl = p3.nr_pickl)
    WHERE
        p1.platz_von like '03*' AND
        p2.platz_von like '04*' AND
        p3.platz_von like '05*'
    GROUP BY
       p1.nr_pickl
```

I know that my query can not work, but I have no idea where my mistake is and if my approach is correct. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: One thing to point out is in your like parts, you should be using % instead of *. A * will search for the literal string `03*`, whereas using a % will match `03`, `03-01-00-00`, `03akjdbdajc` etc.

Comment: Also, try using `count` in place of all of your `sums`

Comment: It is Access SQL which uses non standard LIKEs, such as *.

Comment: @Kickstart Ahh right, sorry saw the MySQL tag so was working from that...

Comment: @Crazyloonybin - no problem. I have had to suffer using Access enough to still have nightmares about its dodgy syntax.

Comment: I'm working with Access and SQLPlus and always mix them up... thank you anyways!

Comment: @Kickstart I've never used Access thank god, heard many complaints about its awkward syntax though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   p1.nr_pickl,
   sum(IIF(LEFT(p1.platz_von, 2) = "03", 1, 0) as Gang_03,
   sum(IIF(LEFT(p1.platz_von, 2) = "04", 1, 0) as Gang_04,
   sum(IIF(LEFT(p1.platz_von, 2) = "05", 1, 0) as Gang_05
FROM
   Pickauf_0110 as p1
GROUP BY p1.nr_pickl
```

EDIT: I haven't tried this for syntax. But this should work in MS-Access.

Comment: @RameshRajendran: `SELECT 
   p1.nr_pickl,
   sum(case when left(p1.platz_von, 2) = '03' then 1 else 0 end) as Gang_03,
   sum(case when left(p1.platz_von, 2) = '04' then 1 else 0 end) as Gang_04,
   sum(case when left(p1.platz_von, 2) = '05' then 1 else 0 end) as Gang_05
FROM
   Pickauf_0110 as p1
GROUP BY p1.nr_pickl`

Comment: @shahkalpesh please explain this code                                                                                                                   sum(case when left(p1.platz_von, 2) = '03'

Comment: @siva: It means, if the left 2 characters are '03', treat current column value as 1, 0 otherwise. Do a sum on it assuming it is either 0 or 1.